# php5-fpm works for a bit and then stops (nginx/wordpress)

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, wordpress

I'm running wordpress on an nginx/php5-fpm setup and every few minutes, php stops working.

When someone tries to subscribe, it works at first and then it stops and takes the user to a 500 server error page.

Initially they load,but shortly after my posts/pages get 404s (except homepage and category pages).

Initially it works, and I have to do a restart to get it running again.

php5-fpm.log once showed this:

```
WARNING: [pool www] server reached pm.max_children setting (5), consider raising it
```

and nothing else.

What could be happening?

/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
http://pastebin.com/C7Emf2B1

/etc/nginx/sites-available/default
http://pastebin.com/Cxg7ETHb

I'm set up through

```
listen = 127.0.0.1:9000
```

in www.conf file

and

```
fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
```

in default server block

socket wasn't working and giving me a wp login loop on top of everything).

Has anyone had any experience with something like this?

Comment: The answer lies in the php-fpm error log. Plus, may be in a nginx error log.

Answer (score 1):

A 3 second Google [bought up a page](http://myshell.co.uk/blog/2012/07/adjusting-child-processes-for-php-fpm-nginx/) that answers all your questions - you just need to raise that limit. Did you try Googleing "pm.max_children" before you posted your question?